# Is there a T-SQL PARSEONLY flag equivalent in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I know that T-SQL supports the [PARSEONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-parseonly-transact-sql) flag, which checks for valid script and returns a message accordingly.

Looking for a way to send command text to the server for parsing. A viable alternative would be a C# MySQL parser, but the former is preferred. I'd rather validate before attempting to execute.

Comment: Would preparing the statement give you an error if there were problems.  This doesn't have to be executed, just prepared.

Comment: @NigelRen I see the C# method for Command.Prepare(). Looking into how this works too. Seems viable so far.

Comment: @NigelRen I had to add a `IgnorePrepare=false` to the connection string, but it throws an error if the statement fails to prepare. This meets my need, so go ahead and submit as an answer and I will accept. This seems better than @Vix- answer execution plans aren't brought into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply preparing the statement would give you an error if there were problems. This doesn't have to be executed, just prepared.

Comment: is it working answer? I tried call prepare but no exception for bad SQL..

Answer (score 1):

Would the [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) statement work? There is a limitation:

> EXPLAIN works with SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, and UPDATE statements.

So it's not universal, but perhaps that's enough?

Comment: Thanks! Testing this out now. Look like it might work if it's only creating an execution plan on success and returning an error message if it fails to parse.